# How to make a copy of a file and place it in the same directory copied from?

Tags: linux, ssh

For instance let's say that my current directory is `Carton` and I'm trying to; make a copy of file `spyware` inside the directory `RYU`, called `spyware.exe` and place it in the `RYU` directory. What would be the fastest way to get there and make those changes.

> My attempt was: `cp ../RYU/spyware ./spyware.exe`

Can I get feedback on how to accomplish this?

```
Directory
-- Directory1
|-- admin
|-- UBC
|   |-- cafeteria
|   `-- library
|-- faculty
|-- history.exe
|-- RYU
|   |-- spyware
|   |-- building1
|   `-- parking
|-- YKU
|   |-- outline.pdf
|   |-- programming
|   |   `-- report.txt
|   `-- security
`-- Carton
    |-- gen-education
    |-- compsci
    |   |-- english.doc
    |   `-- match.txt
    `-- file3
```

Comment: Are you trying to get at `cp ../RYU/spyware ../RYU/spyware.exe`, or do you want to avoid repeating the path in some way?

Comment: yes that was exactly what i was looking for I thought i could just put my `.` directory plus the new file-name. @dhag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cp ../RYU/spyware ../RYU/spyware.exe

Comment: The question has already been answered, but thanks.

Comment: @FrancescStudio strictly speaking, it hasn't. On this site, in order for a question to be marked as answered, you need [to accept](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) an answer. It would be great if you could do so.

Comment: I know @terdon I'm very familiar with this site I'm coming from a different community but the first person who answers the question deserves a check mark.  So dhag do you want to post the answer so I can check mark it?

Comment: @FrancescStudio sorry, I should have checked your profile :). Still, comments don't count. They can be deleted without warning and are easy to miss. Taking someone else's comment and making it into an answer is fair game.